# MySQL Query for finding customer interations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table similar to below:

```
uniqueId | cUniqueId | steps | createdDate
      1  |       345 | step1 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
      2  |       347 | step2 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
      3  |       345 | step3 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
      4  |       545 | step2 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
      5  |       645 | step2 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
      6  |       785 | step3 | 2015-11-29 02:10:27
```

I basically have 3 steps to filling out my application and every time a customer clicks on a step a row is added to my DB, the customers can go to any of the steps at any time and skip a step and then go back if needs be.

I'm attempting to get some insights into how customers interact but the main thing at the moment is working out how many customers went to each step first.

For instance if I had a sample of say 400 the data would look like:

```
FirstStep | amount
    Step1 | 200
    Step2 | 100
    Step3 | 100
```

This would mean that 100 users went to Step2 first etc

Any points in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: Google: SQL group by examples

Comment: Thanks for that, I can group by step which would give me each step and if a user clicked the step but not which step they clicked first, thats where I'm getting stuck (select step, COUNT(distinct uCId) as customerCount  FROM customerSteps where uCId between '1015' and '1846' GROUP BY step)

Comment: OK figured it out: 

select distinct step , count(uCId) as customerCount  

FROM (
select DISTINCT uCId, step,dateCreated 
from customerSteps 
where uCId between '1015' and '1846' 
group by uCId 
ORDER BY dateCreated ASC) 
as customerSteps2 
group by step

Comment: Please post answer so others may benefit.

Comment: Just worked out it's not perfect as I tried to flip it round so I could see the last interaction but it wasn't as simple as changing the order by ASC to DESC.  Will post once complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working (it defines what step was first by date for each user). Replace `table` with your table name:

```
select `table`.`steps`,count(*)
from `table`
inner join (
  SELECT `cUniqueId`,min(`createdDate`) as `date` FROM `table` 
  group by `cUniqueId`
) as `t2` on 
  `table`.`cUniqueId` = `t2`.`cUniqueId` AND
  `table`.`createdDate` = `t2`.`date` 
group by `table`.`steps`
```